# Can I use present perfect twice and present simple + simple past in the same sentence?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

> I **have just checked** your bank account, and it **appears** that you
>   **have already received** all of the money that I **sent** you.

I am not sure if I can use second past perfect verb tense in the same sentence after using present simple, or it has to be simple past: "have already received" -> "received", or "had already received". Grammatically I don't know which one is correct. Could you please provide any examples how to better structure the above sentence?

Comment: Will you please explain what you think is wrong with this question? Otherwise, it will be like you are looking for proof-reading, which is not something that we do here.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use second past perfect verb tense in the same sentence after using present simple, or it has to be simple past: "have already received" -> "received", or "had already received". Grammatically I don't know which one is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have just checked your bank account, and it appears that you have already received all of the money that I sent you.

This is perfectly correct and natural as it stands.

The checking was done in the immediate past. The speaker is making a judgement (it appears) in the present. the money was received in the past, before the checking was done, but after the money was sent.

"received' instead of "have already received" would be correct. "have already received" emphasizes that the receipt occurred in the past, perhaps in response to a suggestion that some of the money was still to come.